# Does luck actually improve your loot?

Tags: wasteland-2

In Wasteland 2, the description for the luck attribute mentions that lucky characters are likely to find better loot. Is this actually true? Has anyone actually tested this or confirmed with the devs?

I do know of at least one other attribute that has a description full of lies: coordination does not actually affect the ability to pick locks or crack safes etc. in any way.

A preliminary look around the forums and community website turned up the usual threads with completely contradictory viewpoints:

- [1](https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=9977), in which everyone reports anecdotally seeing more loot from high luck looters, except for the last poster, who dismisses this entirely based on their own testing
- [2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/664099-wasteland-2/70143848), in which more anecdotal evidence of Scotchmo being better at looting stuff surfaces
- [3](https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=6605), in which people are skeptical that there is any relationship
- [etc.](https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=8713), [etc.](https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=10316)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Luck has nothing to do with loot. An inxile forum member Staherminator checked the code and found out that all loots are not affected by Luck

https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=10819&p=139805&hilit=luck+loot#p138152

Answer (score 1):

Luck is indeed involved. Instead of just taking someones word for it, I actually put an hours work into it and the differneces are slight, but definatly there. Can't post my entire findings here, but inanimate objects looting is where the big difference is so heres my findings on a lower scale (just 50 small loots).

Test made near town entry of Angel Oracle on the 10 hanged men.
Let me show you the numbers from 5 looting sessions by different chars...
All ten corpses looted by:
1) Char with 1 luck; 71, 90, 59, 77, 82 (+5x 7.62 mm bullets).
2) Char with 10 luck; 83, 68, 79, 86, 92 (+6x Shotgun Shells, 5x 7.62 mm bullets, 5x Energy Cells and 6x 9 mm Bullets).
3) Char with luck 10 and all members activated in party (yes, this makes a difference too!); 93, 63, 86, 70, 87 (+10x Shotgun Shells, 12x Energy Cells, 11x 7.62 bullets, 9x 14 mm bullets).

Clearly the 3rd alternative sticks out and with that I mean that OP may be correct in the ordinary looting (the normal loot doesn't give me anything that sticks out), but there's a "bonus" loot, in this case, bullets, that a lower luck person doesn't get frequently, while a higher luck person does. Also, that all of the party is highlighted seems to take into account that all their stats together should be taken into account, not just the person doing the looting.

Best Regards
-Jonas "prinsallan" Aastrand, the Supreme Jerk ;D (500+ hours in more than 5 different teams).

Ps. Entire findings posted on page 2 of this page: https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=10819 Ds.